# Deploying a Rails hello world, I always get 500.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, production-environment

I have my VPS fully configured with nginx + unicorn but I'm unable to get a production site working.

It doesn't matter if is just a Hello World or an app I wrote.

I run my app like:

```
unicorn_rails -c /srv/http/ruby/app/config/unicorn.rb -E development -D
```

And it works like charm, but if I run it on production mode, I always get 500.html

I will put my steps:

```
rails new hello
cd hello
rails g scaffold Person name:string
rake db:migrate
rm public/index.html
```

And I change the route to:

```
root :to => 'people#index'
```

In development mode it works like charm, in production , 500.html and the unicorn log says:

```
cache: [GET /] miss
```

Nothing more on unicorn / nginx logs.

Even without database, just an empty app, 500.html in production.

Otoh, I'm using RubyMine 4 to develop, if I try to run my app in production mode, same error so is not problem of nginx / unicorn.

do I need to configure anything when trying to use production mode?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: On my app I have a redirection in a route to a login page and you can see how to browser redirect to that login page, but always showing the 500.html

**EDIT**: I saw the problem:

Im using this:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", controller_name , :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", controller_name %>
```

And I deleted the **require_tree .** from the js and css.

I dont want to load all the css and js in every page. But thinking about production. Seems like it want to get ALL css and compress it in one and get ALL js and compress it in one js. I dont like that. So, am I stuck?

Comment: I could be wrong but I suspect it's a problem related to assets pipeline (I had a similar behavior with a simple app of mine), have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9144022/455642

Comment: Yup yup, is assets pipeline problem, with config.serve_static_assets to true it works but it seems like the unicorn is using the double of the ram. assets:precompile doesnt work, it precompiles but... not all? Weird.

Comment: Have you run $bundle exec rake assets:precompile in the VPS or in your local machine? What does not precompile?

Comment: I did it on the VPS. Its random, first time was a jpg (deleted assets on public) and next time was a css... Its seems like it doesnt precompile all.

Comment: I updated my question with new stuff.

Comment: maybe [here][1] you could find useful information.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7134034/455642

Comment: Well, this question is done. Please make an answer to end this :P